# Using a hybrid hard drive for storage only-not as a system drive: does the cache still work that way?

Tags: storage

Yes, I know that hybrid hard drives (in this case a Western Digital one terabyte, 16 gig hybrid, 7200 rpm) are primarily designed for running the operating system to give improved performance. It works fine in that role.
But, since I already have solid state drives for Windows 8.1, I am using the WD drive as a second drive for storing and playback of videos and music and other archiving purposes. 
My question is: Does the built-in solid state cache still carry out some sort of role when a hybrid drive is used for storage only? (and not as a Windows system drive) For example, are frequently played videos or music files loaded into the cache for quicker load-up and playback?

Comment: Its going to function exactly like it would.  How it works is independent of any other storage devices.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a hybrid drive as a normal drive with a very large cache. This cache is populated with things your drive guesses you might be wanting, making those things fast to access.

There's a variety of mechanisms by which guessing takes place, but for most purposes, you can use a very simple frequency of use algorithm. This works nicely for OS files, as there's certain things your system accesses a lot.

But it also works fine for other types of data. It's quite easy to predict that if you've starting to stream a video off your HDD, it's -likely- that you'll want the rest of the video quite soon, and therefore premptively cache it.

Your drive is already doing this - every drive these days has some cache built in, because if it only fetched exactly what you asked for, one chunk at a time it would be horribly inefficient. The SSD layer in a hybrid drive is just extending that concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second drive to be fast get another ssd, if you want sometimes fast but lots more room get the hybrid. Just be aware how caching works - it improves read access to collections of files that you open or access repeatedly, or need to open really fast. So if you don't use a program frequently it wont get cached rendering your hybrid drive nothing more that a regular drive. And in case you want just an extra storage space, then just get a HDD.

Hope this helps.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could make a difference, even as secondary drive. The technology to determine what to put into the SSD part is independent of your OS, drivers or filesystem. So Windows will not even be able to give any hints to the drive which files to cache or which not.

A quote form [Western Digital](https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-storage/wd-blue-sshd.html):

> An advanced set of algorithms in the SSHD firmware track and prioritize frequently used data, adapting, learning and optimizing over time and making intelligent determinations without any influence from the host or related storage device drivers.

And another from [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/tech-insights/adaptive-memory-in-sshd-master-ti/):

> Implemented inside of the Seagate SSHD via firmware, Adaptive Memory technology is also referred to as self-learning technology. This is because the SSHD makes intelligent determinations about which data to store in NAND flash memory, without any influence from the host or related storage device drivers. Adaptive Memory technology works by identifying data elements that are important for enhanced host-level performance and promoting such data elements from HDD storage to NAND flash memory.

However: if you are using the secondary drive for streaming video's, playing audio or anything that does not often involve repetitive reading of the same files, you will not have much benefit. In that case it will probably only store the FileSystem data (unless you never open directories repetitively to check their contents or to select the movie you want to view). If that's all you do, you're better off with a normal HDD.

If you do creative work, and open the same files multiple times a day (for example edit pages that contain images), it is likely that the most frequently used files will be cached (so the company's logo will load fast in all documents referencing it).

If you are a programmer and write code, the compiler will read all unedited code over and over each time you recompile your program, so in that area you will benefit for sure.

For gaming i'm sceptical. I'm not a gamer, so I don't know but I think that games are designed in a way that loading will be done far in advance. The HDD speed is not likely to be a factor during the action in a way that your video card will be. The few millisecconds in difference between switching levels and so on will probably be negligible and at a time that it doesn't really matter. You might perform better with the slower drive because your brain gets an extra rest cycle ;-)